# grid of colored squares data visualization

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am looking to represent something that is say, 998 for and 2 against as a grid of 998 green squares and two red squares.  Is that a plot type, hopefully with an R package that does it?

If you are not sure of what I'm taking about, I'm thinking of something like XKCD's chart about radiation here:

https://xkcd.com/radiation/

So it would be one of those blocks of squares, but with, say,2 red ones in the above example.  I just want to show the one-sidedness and I think that would be a good format.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a "waffle chart" -- here's one [R implementation](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle#waffle).

In general you can make such a chart with a scatterplot of square markers placed in a grid.